# RecyclerView startSmoothScroll() incorrect scroll amount with AppBarLayout?

Tags: android

I'm having trouble implementing smooth scroll with a RecyclerView when it is paired with AppBarLayout. This is my layout:

```
<CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />
    </AppBarLayout>

    <RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```

I try to scroll to a position like so:

```
RecyclerView.SmoothScroller ss = new LinearSmoothScroller(getActivity()) {
        @Override protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
            return LinearSmoothScroller.SNAP_TO_END;
        }
    };
ss.setTargetPosition(position);
llm.startSmoothScroll(ss);
```

There are two problems:

1. If the target position is off the bottom edge of the recycler view, the scroll amount is incorrect - it is offset by the height of the AppBarLayout. If I change to `SNAP_TO_START`, then it works fine. Or, if I remove the AppBarLayout, it works fine in all cases.
2. Attempting to scroll to the last element in the recycler view is broken in additional ways. The `SNAP_TO_START` flag usually works fine (see #1), but in this case the recycler view refuses to scroll it up completely.

So removing the AppBarLayout fixes everything, is there some additional setting needed when using this with AppBarLayout? I'm on the latest support library version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use `smoothScrollToPosition` to fix your issue as below.

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
rv.smoothScrollToPosition(mMessages.count-1);
```

Comment: Yes but I want to control the snap behavior - I want to be able to specify snap to start or end. I believe `smoothScrollToPosition()` does not guarantee that the item will even be fully visible! - also just tried it, but still shows the same broken behavior when `AppBarLayout` is present.

Answer (score 0):

the fist solution is

```
@Override
public int calculateDyToMakeVisible(View view, int snapPreference) {
    return super.calculateDyToMakeVisible(view, snapPreference) - offset;
}
```

where offset may be

```
offset = getActionBarHeight(context);
public int getActionBarHeight(@NonNull Context context) {
    final TypedArray ta = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            new int[] {android.R.attr.actionBarSize});
    int actionBarHeight = (int) ta.getDimension(0, 0);
    return actionBarHeight;
}
```

the second solution is to replace app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" with app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways" to prevent the actionBar from hiding